# Regex that should not allowed certain special characters

Tags: regex

I'm creating regex for password. I need regex that should not allow special characters "{}|~".

I'm able to find regex for other cases as we required. Wanted to know regex for provided special characters {}|~ should not be allowed in password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex

```
^[^{}|~]*$
```

should do

check the demo at [101regex](https://regex101.com/r/9XnLAi/2)